# I'm getting 500s while LIMIT / block http POST request w/ Apache(

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, spam

I'm trying to use [core - Apache HTTP Server's `<LIMIT>` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limit) to limit spamers from doing `POST`'s to my website(s):

```
<Limit POST>
        Order deny,allow
        Include /usr/local/apache2/conf/list.acl 
        Allow from all
</Limit>
```

and here is my `list.acl`

```
# cat /usr/local/apache2/conf/list.acl | tail -1
Deny from 222.0.0.0/8
#
```

Yet, I'm getting 500s. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) What does the Apache error log say?  (2) It's hard to be sure what the cause is, because you've only shown us the last line of list.acl.

Comment: Is your configuration within a .htaccess file?  If so, the `Include` directive isn't allowed there.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman error_log shows me `500` error, that's it( no more details .htaccess is empty other than `<LIMIT>` and `list.acl` contains big list of network ranges.

Comment: so I moved this into main configuration file instead of `.htaccess`, yet while it doesn't produce error 500 anymore it still not limiting users from doing `POST`s( any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Read the description of [`Order Deny,Allow`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) in the Apache docs:

> Deny,Allow
>     First, all Deny directives are evaluated; if any match,
>     the request is denied   unless it also matches an Allow directive. Any
>     requests which do not match   any Allow or Deny directives are
>     permitted.

So your `Allow from all` is overriding your `Deny` directives.

I think you want to switch to `Order Allow,Deny`.  If you read carefully the description of that in the Apache docs, you'll see that it's what you want instead.